# Add Currency Sign £, $ to certain fields ORACLE

Tags: oracle, currency, sign

I want to display the dollar or pound sign in my fields that hold job_salary any one knows? how to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `$` in the format mask hardcodes a dollar sign (after all, Oracle is an American corporation).  Other currencies are determined by the setting for NLS_TERRITORY.  Use `C` to see the ISO currency abbreviation (UKP) and `L` for the symbol (£).

```
SQL> select to_char(sal, 'C999,999.00') as ISO
  2         , to_char(sal, 'L999,999.00') as symbol from emp
  3  /

ISO                SYMBOL
------------------ ---------------------
       GBP3,500.00             £3,500.00
       GBP3,750.00             £3,750.00 

...
```

Answer (score 1):

My preference is:

```
select to_char(123456789.91, 'FM$999,999,999,990.00')
  from dual;
```

Build the format string out to as many digits as you need. The FM skips the leading space to account for negative number alignment.

select to_char((123456789.91, 'FM999,999,999,990.00C')
from dual;

This will get the ISO value trimming the leading space