# How to prefix a SQL query on a numerical column with £ symbol

Tags: sql, oracle, symbols, oracle-apex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add Currency Sign £, $ to certain fields ORACLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717686/add-currency-sign-to-certain-fields-oracle)

I have a table of values that represent money, I want to prefix the SQL query output with a £ sign.

Is there anyway of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
SELECT to_char( column_name, '£999,999,999.99' ) 
  FROM table_name
```

assuming you want to hard-code the currency symbol and the formatting.  If you want to use the session's NLS settings to determine the appropriate currency symbol and grouping symbol

```
SELECT to_char( column_name, 'L999G999G999D99' ) 
  FROM table_name
```

Breaking that down

- L is the local currency symbol
- G is the grouping symbol (a comma in the US)
- D is the decimal separator (a period in the US)

Comment: Could that also be used in conjunction with a AVG? This is my current query...

SELECT car_type,  AVG(caravan.rental_caravan) as Average  FROM caravan_category
 JOIN caravan ON caravan.caravan_type_id = caravan_category.caravan_type_id
GROUP BY car_type
ORDER BY Average desc;

Comment: @user1887939 - Sure, you can nest the function calls (`to_char( avg( caravan.rental_caravan ), 'L999G999G999D99')`)

Comment: Fantastic :D Great Help - VERY MUCH appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use something like: `to_char(money, '£9999.00')`.

Details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm).

Comment: Duplicate of [Add Currency Sign £, $ to certain fields ORACLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717686/add-currency-sign-to-certain-fields-oracle)