# show currency in APEX in euro's

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, sql-date-functions, ora-01481

In Oracle's apex you can do `to_char( moneycolumn, '$9,999.99')`.

But when I do `to_char( moneycolumn, '€9.999,99')`

I get: *ORA-01481: invalid number format model*

So how can I convert float values to euro format like:

- €400,-
- €4,99
- €1.000,23
- €23.384,-

Comment: Just to explain: the `$` symbol in a format model is part of Oracle's number format syntax, it is not related to any particular currency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2717930/5444242) might help.

You may supply currency as part of `NLSPARAM` - 3rd optional argument of `to_char` function - see the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm). Or you may alter `NLS_TERRITORY` setting with `ALTER SESSION` command. Or maybe the `to_char(500,'L999G999D00')` will even work out of the box depending on your database value for `NLS_TERRITORY`.

Comment: `to_char(MAANDLAST,'L99G999D99MI', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.'' NLS_CURRENCY = ''€'' ')` this works thanks for doc link

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness - to include arbitrary characters in a number format, you can delimit them with double quotes, e.g. `to_char( moneycolumn, '"€"9.999,99')` - however in this case since you just want to use a different symbol for the currency I'd recommend using the accepted answer from Peter.