# How to use the euro symbol in PL/SQL code?

Tags: html, oracle, plsql

Please I have a PL/SQL package where I'm using HTML code.

In the HTML code I need to use the euro symbol (as its HTML code) but when I use `&euro;` the PL/SQL package considers like if i want to pass him a variable and he keep asking me about the value of euro.

Is there any option that makes the use of `&euro;` possible in a PL/SQL package?

```
phrase_conditionnelle := 'Le montant de '||mt_salaire||
                                         ' €</b> ;
```

Comment: you can check this link [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717686/add-currency-sign-%C2%A3-to-certain-fields-oracle

Comment: The line of code you posted used the actual euro symbol, not the HTML encoding; and it is missing a closing quote. Please show exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Currency Sign £, $ to certain fields ORACLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717686/add-currency-sign-%c2%a3-to-certain-fields-oracle)

Comment: This is specifically about handling the encoded form `&euro;`, not the actual euro symbol character - though that wasn't clear from the question's original formatting. So that suggested duplicate doesn't actually seem to be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your client is interpreting the `&euro;` as [a substitution variable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB):

```
SQL> select '&euro;' from dual;
Enter value for euro:
```

You can disable that behaviour with `set define off` in SQL*Plus, SQL Developer or SQLcl:

```
SQL> set define off
SQL> select '&euro;' from dual;

'&EURO
------
&euro;

1 row selected.

SQL> set define on; -- optional but restores behaviour
```

This is nothing to do with PL/SQL really, or even SQL; it's just client behaviour, at the point you try to compile the package - the client is interpreting the `&` before it passes any code to the database for processing. That also means that sessions *calling* your package don't need to worry about that setting.

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the possible way to do that.
just replace `&` by `chr(38)`

```
phrase_conditionnelle := 'Le montant de '||mt_salaire|| chr(38)||'euro;' ;
```